# Reading a log file into 2D/1D array in bash script

Tags: bash

I have a file log.txt as below

```
1    0.694003    5.326995    7.500997    6.263974     0.633941    36.556128
2    2.221990    4.422010    4.652992    5.964420     0.660997    51.874905
3    4.376005    7.440002    6.260000    6.238917     0.728308    10.927455
4    1.914000    5.451991    0.668012    6.355688     0.634081   106.733134
5    2.530005    0.000000    8.084005    3.916278     0.687023  2252.538670
6    1.997993    1.406001    7.977006    3.923551     0.517551    37.611894
7    0.971998    1.823007    8.804005    4.110159     0.567905   905.995133
8    0.480005    3.109009    8.711002    4.060954     0.508963   553.712280
9    1.015001    3.996992    7.781004    3.547329     0.396635    16.883011
```

I want to read 6th column of this file into an array myArray so that it will give below:

```
echo ${myArray[9]} = 0.396635
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do this (bash 4+), assuming `log.txt`'s first column starts at 1 and doesn't skip any numbers.

```sh
readarray -t myArray < <(tr -s ' ' < log.txt | cut -d' ' -f6)
echo ${myArray[8]}
```

- `tr -s ' '` collapses the whitespace, for easier manipulation
- `cut -d' ' -f6` selects the 6th space separated column
- `<(...)` turns the subcommand into a temporary file
- `readarray` reads lines from the file into the variable `myArray`

Note that the array is 8 indexed, so I've selected `[8]` instead of `[9]`.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption:

- first column of file is an integer
- first column of file may not be sequential
- OP wants (needs?) the array index to match the value in the first column

Sample data file:

```
$ cat log.txt
3    4.376005    7.440002    6.260000    6.238917     0.728308    10.927455
5    2.530005    0.000000    8.084005    3.916278     0.687023  2252.538670
7    0.971998    1.823007    8.804005    4.110159     0.567905   905.995133
9    1.015001    3.996992    7.781004    3.547329     0.396635    16.883011
23    0.480005    3.109009    8.711002    4.060954     0.508963   553.712280
```

One idea using `awk` (to parse the input file):

```
$ awk '{print $1,$6}' log.txt
3 0.728308
5 0.687023
7 0.567905
9 0.396635
23 0.508963
```

We can then feed this into a `while` loop to build the array:

```
unset myArray

while read -r ndx value
do
    myArray["${ndx}"]="${value}"
done < <(awk '{print $1,$6}' log.txt)
```

Verify contents of array:

```
$ typeset -p myArray
declare -a myArray=([3]="0.728308" [5]="0.687023" [7]="0.567905" [9]="0.396635" [23]="0.508963")

$ for ndx in "${!myArray[@]}"
do
    echo "index = ${ndx} ; value = ${myArray[${ndx}]}"
done
index = 3 ; value = 0.728308
index = 5 ; value = 0.687023
index = 7 ; value = 0.567905
index = 9 ; value = 0.396635
index = 23 ; value = 0.508963
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using just bash4+ builtins. (if acceptable)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mapfile -t rows < log.txt
read -ra column <<< "${rows[8]}"
echo "${column[5]}"
```